# Manter um determinado frame dentro de um app android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Estou tentando manipular a taxa de quadros (frame rate) dentro de uma cena do unity, quando eu executo ela na plataforma unity, ela funciona com o determinado valor de quadros que mandei. Porém, quando passo ela para o meu celular, ela varia de 25 a 30 fps.

-> Já mudei o v sync count -> don't use

-> Já mudei o frame diretamente no AndroidUnityPlayer.cs

-> Já usei Time.captureFramerate

-> E estou usando este código para mudar o frame:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class FPSScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float updateInterval = 0.5F;
    private float lastInterval;
    private int frames = 0;
    private float fps;

    void Start() {
        lastInterval = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        frames = 0;

        Application.targetFrameRate = 10;

    }

    void OnGUI() {
        GUILayout.Label("" + fps.ToString("f2"));
    }

    void Update() {
        ++frames;
        float timeNow = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        if (timeNow > lastInterval + updateInterval) {
            fps = frames / (timeNow - lastInterval);
            frames = 0;
            lastInterval = timeNow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A partir desse modelo consegui os valores que queria dentro do desktop. Também fiz diretamente nas classes que capturam a cena pela função Awake(). Mas consegui obter os valores desejados alterando configurações de tempo no unity.

Answer (score 5):

Gostaria de compartilhar a resolução desse problema, já que senti uma certa carência de material ajudando, seja em inglês ou em português. Primeiramente, o v sync desativado ajuda sim, mas por default o android vai sempre rodar com 30 fps ou pelo menos isso! Então fui no project settings e alterei valores relacionados a tempo como: Fixed Timestep - é um intervalo do frame rate que faz os cálculos da cena, como precisava de algo menos de 20 fps, alterei esse valor para 0.0005 (por default ele vem 0.02), também alterei o Maximum Allowed Timestep -  é o intervalo de frame rate máximo que a cena pode atingir, quando é usado o Application.targetFrameRate esse valor fica 0.33333 (ou seja, na maioria dos casos pelo menos 30 fps a cena terá) alterei esse valor para 0.2!

Não, o valor do frame não fica exato, mas agora a cena funciona dentro do intervalo de tempo que eu precisava.. Sou novata ainda com a programação em RA e unity, mas aconselho quem queira valores mais exatos a trabalhar diretamente no desktop.